# SOQL for Many to Many Relationship

Tags: soql, relationships

I have a many to many relationship  between Opportunity and custom_object__c with  the junction object junction_object__c. Now I have to frame a query to pull  all the related/attached custom_object__c records with the fields  from Opportunity. How can I do that?

Comment: Probably best if you look through the [Relationship Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) documentation and find the pattern that matches what you need.

Comment: @Thanks keith: I framed the query using the relationship model between the objects.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend starting your SOQL query at the common denominator, which would be the child object of both Parents (Junction_Object__c) in your case.

```
SELECT ID, Opportunity.[field_Name__c], Custom_Object__c.[field_Name__c], [...]
FROM Junction_Object__c  
WHERE 
[Write your Opp/Custom Object filters here]
```

With this, you should be able to filter for any opportunity/custom object meeting your requirements, then also on the junction object records themselves if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following should select Id from your custom object and Id from opportunity and you can add more fields that you want to select. Just add your WHERE clause after it.

SELECT Id, (SELECT Opportunity__r.Id FROM junction_objects__r) FROM custom_object__c

One thing to keep in mind is if you go to your junction_object and view the master detail fields you created for your join relationship. Go first to the field for the relationship to custom_object__c you will see a part where you can name the child relationship name and related list label. "junction_objects__r" you get from that name. The field name for the other relationship is where Opportunity__r comes from.